# Find rows starting with non-alpha sign

Tags: php, mysql, regex, prepared-statement

Having this code:

```
$val_sql = "";
$stm = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP ?");
$stm->bindValue(1, $val_sql, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->execute();
```

How do I find rows NOT starting with alpha signs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to:

```
$val_sql = "^[^a-z]";
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked with `^[^a-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ0-9]`.